# Can't control the position of .appendChild() after .cloneNode()

Tags: javascript, angular

First things first, sorry but the code just won't run in a snippet. Neither codepan, or jsfiddle. I'm still uploading it here, but try maybe to run it locally. I'm using Angular CLI project in WebStorm.

What I want to do in my app is to create something like to-do list. When clicking on "Create a New List" a new rectangle (to-do card) should be created, right next to it. Not below it, not on top, but on it's right.

I did `.cloneNode()` and `.appendChild()`. It does the trick, but my problem is that I can't control the positioning of the result of `.appenChild()`. It always inserts the new to-do card below the existing one.

Please, someone bring peace to my mind!!

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ShoppingList'; // application name
  products = []; // array declaration
  itemToAdd;
  itemToRemove;

  /* --- adds an item in the array --- */
  addNewItem () {
    if (this.itemToAdd !== null) {
      this.products.push(this.itemToAdd)
    }
  }

  /* --- removes all items from array --- */
  removeItem () {
    const index = this.products.indexOf(this.itemToRemove)
    if (index > -1) {
      this.products.splice(index)
    }
  }

  /* --- creates new list  --- */
  createNewList () {
    const elementToClone = document.getElementById('listCard')
    const clone = elementToClone.cloneNode(true)
    document.getElementById('mainContent').appendChild(clone)
    console.log(this.products)
    console.log(clone)
  }
}
```

```css
.mainContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.listCard {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.listTextAndButtons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

.textAreas {
  display: flex;
}

.addRemoveButtons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.createNewListButton {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

textarea {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #767676;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

button {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #767676;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ShoppingList</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mainContent" class="mainContent">

  <div id="listCard" class="listCard"></div>

  <div class="listTextAndButtons">
    <label class="textAreas">
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="itemToAdd"></textarea>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="itemToRemove"></textarea>
    </label>

    <div class="addRemoveButtons">
      <button (click)="addNewItem()">Add New Item!</button>
      <button (click)="removeItem()">Remove an Item!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="createNewListButton">
      <button (click)="createNewList()">Create a New List!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it;s cause your .mainContent is flex-direction: column;, you need row. oh and in this case listTextAndButtons should be inside listCard

Comment: @ihorbond it did work. You are the hero. Regarding putting buttons and textAreas inside the listCard itself, well, I did try a lot to somehow fix them on the bottom of the card, so that the buttons would span the whole width of the card. But I didn't manage. There was always a small gap left at the end. Because of that actually I moved on and changed the design to what it is now. Maybe you can help me with a code on how to do that? I would appreciate plain CSS, don't want to mix any frameworks or libraries yet.

Comment: hey have you had the chance do look at my answer, was it helpful ?

Comment: Hey I just now checked it out. It helped, yes. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d3u18o), take a look. I removed the

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

from HTML template as you are obviously on angular 2+

Regarding the flexbox I gave listCard a max-width property and set flex-wrap: wrap on .listTextArea , the direction is row by default so new items will be added to the right until they reach max-width and then wrap onto a new line. I always refer to this [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) when it comes to flexbox

```
.listCard {
    max-width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.listTextArea {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Also, I'd recommend to follow the same pattern for lists as I did with items inside list e.g. instead of cloning and appending new node keep lists in an array and loop thru it with *ngFor

```
<div class="listCard" *ngFor="let list of todoLists">
```